# Problems creating an ad-hoc network in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet-connection, ad-hoc-network, ics

Windows 7: I created an ad-hoc network (wireless for 2 laptops), it worked fine - we could use the internet with no problems. The next day I tried to make again the ad-hoc network, I went through all the steps I did before, BUT, when I’m asked for network name, I put it there and then it just creates the network with local access only!  It doesn’t even ask me anymore if I want to share the internet connection.

I don’t know what to do now, suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The simpler solution is to use something like [**VirtualRouter**](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) or [**Connectify**](http://www.connectify.me/), which use Windows 7's virtual WiFi support to create an access point using your wireless card. This allows other computers to connect as if they were using a regular wireless access point, without any ad-hoc networks.